# Populate Firebase database using server

Tags: android, firebase

I need to prepare data for Android client and put them on server using some of Google products(like Firebase)
I need something like a server which parse site and put data in the Firebase. 
Can  I do this and how?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you have, then mention it on your question and tell on which step did you fail. A lot of us want to help you but please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Anyway, welcome to StackOverflow :)